# How to switch view modes in built-in Diff viewer of Visual Studio 2012 and 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, compare, diff

Currently, this is how Visual Studio displays the differences between files:

[image]

I would like it to display the two files separately (including the red/green notations), as I believe is the default settings. How do I change the way it displays the differences?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Check the *'Compare Files'* toolbox, there is a button for it.

Or use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Had that issue for months.. This is embarrassing. Thanks